# Batch file for creating files according to the days in a month

Tags: windows, batch-file

### Update

This is not working in my office pc. When i specificy the current month day as only 2. This is an data which it throws:-

> How many Days this month: 2 The Month is (Blank) The Day is (Blank)
> The Year is (Blank) the Month is 2 days long C:\Documents and
> Settings\Desktop\hi\act\01--.xls C:\Documents and
> Settings\Desktop\hi\act\2--.xls C:\Documents and
> Settings\Desktop\hi\act\Master File.xls 1 file(s) copied. C:\Documents
> and Settings\Desktop\hi\act\01--.xls C:\Documents and
> Settings\Desktop\hi\act\06-Mar-2012.xls C:\Documents and
> Settings\Desktop\hi\act\2--.xls C:\Documents and
> Settings\Desktop\hi\act\Master File.xls 1 file(s) copied. C:\Documents
> and Settings\Desktop\hi\act\01--.xls C:\Documents and
> Settings\Desktop\hi\act\06-Mar-2012.xls C:\Documents and
> Settings\Desktop\hi\act\Master File.xls 1 file(s) copied

.

### Original Question Below

There is an excel file for each day of the month. I need to create the Excel file for each day as per the date.

For example: There are 31 days in month of January, so the Excel files in each month's folder will be

```
01-01-12.xls
02-01-12.xls
03-01-12.xls
...
31-01-12.xls
```

Is it possible?

---

I tried this in a `.bat` file but I don't know how to construct the loop:

```
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %%A in ('Date /t') do @( 
Set Day=%%A
Set Month=%%B
Set Year=%%C
Set All=%%A%%B%%C
)

@For %%a in ("*.xls") do copy %%a "import\%All%.xls"
```

Comment: @Uday because your accounts aren't associated because you used two different email addresses, so I can't help associate your accounts. Either way, please keep using the account you used to edit this question

Comment: What do you mean "There is an excel file for each day of the month" What are the names currently, of your excel files,  prior to running anything?

Comment: I missed your last comment. Do you have enough rep to join the discussion now?

Comment: @barlop now i can come for discussion as I have got 21 rep now. Please tell me when to come to chat.

Comment: the chat is not live, so just go in now and type what you want and when i'm online i'll type what I want, then you come in later and type what you want etc. we don't have to be in there at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
set /P max=How many Days this month:  

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=- " %%a in ('date /T') do @(
    set y=%%c
    set m=%%b
    set d=%%a

)

echo The Month is %m%
echo The Day is %d%
echo The Year is %y%
echo the Month is %max% days long
set d=01
Set /a max=%max%+1

:loop

SET adate=%d%-%m%-%y%

if not exist "C:\Documents and Settings\NGLD7640\Desktop\hi\act\%adate%.xls" copy "C:\Documents and Settings\NGLD7640\Desktop\hi\act\Master File.xls" "C:\Documents and Settings\NGLD7640\Desktop\hi\act\%adate%.xls"

set /a d=%d%+1

if not %d%==%Max% goto loop
```

Code adjusted and customized based on [this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2693/discussion-between-barlop-and-raystafarian) with @[barlop](https://superuser.com/users/42672/barlop).

Answer (score 0):

Here is oneliner that will create today's file.

```
echo "" > { echo (gettime()+".xls") }
```

This is in biterscripting. Put this in a file x.txt file, then schedule this command to run every day thru task scheduler.

```
C:/biterscripting/biterscripting.exe x.txt
```